# Question regarding Java generics in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, generics

The Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) has an example for using AsyncTask, in this example the DownloadFilesTask class extends AsyncTask in a rather odd way (for a beginners perspective at least):

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
```

Shouldn't AsyncTask be accepting type variables instead of primitive types? And what happens if I want to input strings in all 3 parameters? Like so:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
```

How does the class then reference these parameters individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those generic typs only define what kind of input types you have for `<Param, Progress, Result>` meaning that all the params to `execute()` are of type `Param`, those for `onProgressUpdate` are of `Progress` and that `doInBackground()` will return something of type `Result`. The generics only define the *type* of stuff that is expected later.

If you have a decent IDE, when you define the `class X extends AsyncTask<...>` it will provide you with the callbacks where all the right types are filled in.

In your 2nd example -- that does not mean that `execute()` expects 3 Strings - actually it expects one or more variables of type `Param`, as it is a varargs signature. Within the method, you would then reference the individiual instances like accessing an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at that page you linked to, the type parameters are actually named `Params`, `Progress`, and `Result`. That's how the class reference those type parameters. In their example, then:

- `Params` is bound to the type `URL`
- `Progress` is bound to the type `Integer`
- `Result` is bound to the type `Long`

See the documentation on what each of those types is used for.

Answer (score 0):

The Android documentation explains that class AsyncTask has 3 parameters:
`android.os.AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`

So, first class parameter defines the type of arguments that are passed to AsyncTask. Obviously it depends on your task. The give URL as a example but you can use any class or primitive wrapper.

The second class parameter helps you to define how do you want to get status updates during task execution. The use Integer meaning that the example can estimate percentage of task completion. You can use String instead that will be used to define the task phase (e.g. starting, connecting, parsing, analyzing, closing...)

Result defines what does your task return. You can use any type here.

BTW, I'd recommend you to read something about java generics. It can help you to learn other APIs.

Answer (score 0):

It's accepting primitive types because of java auto-boxing feature: Integer and int are interchangeable  - java will use Integer.getInt() if the code needs an int, or use new Integer(int) if it needs an Integer etc. This applies to all primitive types and their corresponding class (long vs Long, float vs Float, etc)